# Lotus Notes Single Sign On through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, single-sign-on, lotus-notes

I have a script that works with a Lotus database:

```
$LotusSession = New-Object -ComObject Lotus.NotesSession 
$LotusSession.Initialize()
$LotusDatabase = $LotusSession.GetDatabase('Server','Database.nsf');
$DocView = $LotusDatabase.GetView('ViewName');

$searchkey = # anything

$doc = $DocView.GetAllDocumentsByKey($searchkey,$false);

<# ... and so on ... #>
```

Can I somehow initialize the session without entering a password each time, but using a Lotus SSO which is installed and works with my Lotus installation?

P.S. ID files are created with a restricted policy, so I can't simple check the box "Don't prompt for a password from other Notes-based programs" - it unchecks itself automatically in a short time.

**Edit:** As mentioned below i can't use Lotus SSO. But if there's a chance that I'm able to use Windows SSO since my passwords for a domain account and Lotus ID file are identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already mostly answered your own question. Since the policy is preventing you from checking that option, no you cannot use the SSO option that Notes provides for you.

That said, can you write your own SSO? Yes, you can. It requires writing C code using the Notes C API's Extension Manager features, then compiling the C code into a DLL and listing that DLL in the ExtMgr_Addins line in your notes.ini file. I'm afraid that feature may also be controlled by policies, though, so it might not work.